# Dual delta and epsilon

Tags: option-pricing, greeks

Hey I know that dual delta and epsilon are derivative of option price with respect to strike nad dividend yield respectively. Are they used for something or rather not? Because I heard that dual delta means the probability of finishing ITM but I have not found a justification why this is so. But I also heard that Delta represents probability of finishing ITM.

Comment: You look for the Breeden and Litzenberger (1978) result. The first derivative of the call option price wrt the strike is the risk neutral distribution function and its second partial derivative is the risk neutral density function. Delta is not the risk neutral probability of finishing in the money. It’s a probability under a different measure (called stock/share measure) which results from a numeraire change. You’ll find many explanations about these topics if you browse some old questions.

Comment: See also https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33768/what-is-dual-delta