# Practical use of Dual Delta?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, greeks, european-options

I am wondering what the **practical** use of the Black-Scholes Dual-Delta is?

I know it is the first derivative wrt the strike price:

$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial K} = -\omega e^{-r T} \Phi(\omega d_2)
$$

where $\omega = +1$ for a call and $\omega = -1$ for a put.

But I don't have any intuition of the practical use, since the strike is fixed over the life of an option contract.

There are some questions [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33768/what-is-dual-delta) and [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/59481/dual-delta-and-epsilon), but a practical use does not seem to be given. One answer suggests that it is used to compute local volatility, but I do not know how this would be done.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It's linked to the Breeden-Litzenberger (1978) formula and the extraction of a risk-neutral distribution from observed option prices.